# Bizarre IMAP issue with Outlook 2013

Tags: email, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013

Have a client that is using Outlook 2013 with a GoDaddy hosted IMAP email account. This was recently setup and they created a number of new folders by right clicking on the left side near Inbox and selecting New Folder. They then moved a number of very important emails into several of these folders.  Within several minutes they started receiving popups in Outlook stating something along the lines of "IMAP server does not allow a top level folder created here" at which point the folders began to show up on the side with the tag (This computer only) indicating they were now local only folders.  This wouldn't have been a problem if the emails could be copied back out of the folders and into the Inbox but after several minutes the folders all disappeared from the tree listing and were nowhere to be found, not in the trash and no longer on the server. Unfortunately the only other computer configured with OL2013 and this same IMAP account was turned on and synced the changes before it could be taken offline to export the missing emails. Spoke to GoDaddy tech support and had them roll the mailbox to two days prior but the emails are still not on the server.

I understand that Ooutlook 2013 has made major changes to IMAP operations and now uses an OST file to store data. Any idea if there is a way to extract these disappeared "This computer only" folders from the OST file?

Has anyone else experienced something like this?